# Load Bean property value from database - Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a bean (Iconstant) which has all the constant declared. I have declared the bean definition in `beans.xml` file. I want to load the bean property values from database. Basically, some of the values would be assigned in the `beans.xml` file itself and i want some to be loaded from database itself. for eg, output location of a file. 
I searched the internet, and all i could found is through propertyplaceholder.

So, is there any way to load the bean property value through Database ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use `init-method` or `@AfterConstruct` to initiate values of this bean and inject the DAO to this bean to be used to read data from database

Comment: And to prevent the next question, you cannot do this with a proxied transaction manager :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could also be a case for injecting a  value from a property file
create a file

```
myConstants.properties
```

it could have this in

```
web.title=stack
```

then in cotnext definition do this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myConstants.properties"/>
```

And in your java you can do this

```
@Value("${web.title}")
private String myTitle;
```